# Google Speech API: Can recognize speech from OGG file

Tags: speech-recognition, google-speech-api

I'm using Google Speech API to recognize Vietnamese speech in an .OGG file audio using Python. But it doesn't give back any results.

Answer (score 0):

At least in the English version of the Google Speech API, you need to use a FLAC input file or a Linear 16 input file (not OGG audio format).

See this troubleshooting page for more context: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

Try using this config, for me works using nodejs

```
const config = {
  encoding: 'OGG_OPUS',
  sampleRateHertz: 16000,
  languageCode: 'YOUR_LAUNGAGE CODE'
}
```

I'm working with telegram audio file that are OGA